# Что означает число при добавлении в "Избранное"?

Tags: поддержка, избранное

Добавил два вопроса в избранное до момента посещения вкладки "Избранное", а высветилось "7".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что означает это число?

Comment: семь новых действий (с момента последнего открытия вкладки) с этими вопросами, наверное

Comment: это общее число вопросов в избранном у тебя

Comment: а я не уверен что это ответ - зайди на эту вкладку, по идее число должно пропасть

Comment: @mymedia, скорее с момента последнего посещения этой вкладки в избранное было добавлено 7 вопросов/ответов

Comment: @Grundy, вопросов ли?? Дело в том, что вопросы туда добавляются вручную самим пользователем. Ответы же могут появляться без участия пользователя. Однако я заметил, что иногда сообщения в этом списке поднимаются наверх (и счётчик увеличивается), даже когда там появляются лишь комментарии (к вопросу или ответам на него).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перевод ответа на аналогичный вопрос на MSE: [Why does my favorite count vary on my profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190521/339911)

Число показывает кол-во комментариев и новых или отредактированных ответов на ваши избранные вопросы.